# How to create model classes using JSONModel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization, jsonmodel

I am trying to create Model Class by using [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel).My json Dictionary after using `NSJSONSerialization` looks like below.

```
      {
apiStatus =     {
    message = SUCCESS;
    success = 1;
};
boardingPoints = "<null>";
inventoryType = 0;
seats =     (
            {
        ac = 0;
        available = 1;
        bookedBy = "<null>";
        commission = "<null>";
        fare = 1200;


    },
            {
        ac = 0;
        available = 1;
        bookedBy = "<null>";
        commission = "<null>";
        fare = 1200;


    },

  );
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
   {"boardingPoints":null,"inventoryType":0,"apiStatus":{"success":true,"message":"‌​SUCCESS"},"seats":[{"fare":1200,"commission":null,"bookedBy":null,"ac":false,"ava‌​ilable":true},{"fare":1200,"commission":null,"bookedBy":null,"ac":false,"availabl‌​e":true},]}
```

I have a model class like this :-

```
 @interface Seat : JSONModel

 @property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *ac;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *available;
 @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *bookedBy;
 @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *comission;
 @property(nonatomic)NSNumber * fare;
```

For mapping keys I have done like this:-

```
 +(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper {
return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"ac":@"ac",
                                                   @"available":@"available",
                                                   @"bookedBy":@"bookedBy",
                                                   @"commission":@"commission",
                                                   @"fare":@"fare", }];
```

}

However when I try to use this model I get the following error:

```
[JSONModel.m:252] Incoming data was invalid [Seat initWithDictionary:]. Keys missing: {(
bookedBy,
comission,
available,
ac,
fare,

)}

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

I am using it like this:

```
 //Using JSON Model.
    NSError *jsonError;
    seat = [[Seat alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonDictionary error:&jsonError];
    jsonArray = @[seat.ac,seat.available,seat.bookedBy,seat.comission,seat.fare];
    NSLog(@"JSON Model Array : %@", jsonArray);
```

How to use it correctly?

Comment: Your JSON format does not pass JSONLint - correct it and I will help you

Comment: {"boardingPoints":null,"inventoryType":0,"apiStatus":{"success":true,"message":"SUCCESS"},"seats":[{"fare":1200,"commission":null,"bookedBy":null,"ac":false,"available":true},{"fare":1200,"commission":null,"bookedBy":null,"ac":false,"available":true},]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to override `+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper` if your property names matches with the field names. Try putting the optional keyword for fields that can be null.

```
@interface Seat : JSONModel

@protocol Seat;

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *ac;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString<Optional> *available;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString<Optional> *bookedBy;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *comission;
@property(nonatomic)NSNumber * fare;

@end
```

Taking this a step further, you can do cascading in your top class like this:

```
//Result.h
#import "Seat.h"
#import "APIStatus.h"
@interface Result: JSONModel

@property(nonatomic,strong) APIStatus *apiStatus;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString<Optional> *boardingPoints;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray<Seat> *seats;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *boardingPoints;

@end

//APIStatus.h
@interface APIStatus: JSONModel

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *message;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *success;

@end
```

**EDIT**: This way you only need to init the Result model with JSONModel, all the intermediary classes will be created automatically. You may need to play around with the property types. JSONModel's github page offers good amount of explanations if you need a reference.

Comment: Okay...And How to implement this Result Model class then? :-]

Comment: Okay....Instead of Results I just changed it to 'SeatResult'....and for initialising I did like this....  seatResult = [[SeatResult alloc]initWithData:responseData error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"Seats Array : %@",seatResult.seats); ....and its showing data...thanks KAAN ..although I still need to access the array to see how I can access it.

Comment: Glad it helps, please accept the answer if it solves your initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to correct your JSON string - remove the comma after the last entry of seats.
2. I think you may have to indicate you are working with nested models here i.e. seats are a nested model of your top level model which at this point is anonymous but really denoted by the top level { } braces.

Have a look at this - it describes how to set things up with nested models.

[JSONModel tutorial covering nested models](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-jsonmodel--cms-19840)

Here is your corrected JSON string:

```
{
"boardingPoints": null,
"inventoryType": 0,
"apiStatus": {
    "success": true,
    "message": "‌​SUCCESS"
},
"seats": [
    {
        "fare": 1200,
        "commission": null,
        "bookedBy": null,
        "ac": false,
        "ava‌​ilable": true
    },
    {
        "fare": 1200,
        "commission": null,
        "bookedBy": null,
        "ac": false,
        "availabl‌​e": true
    }
]}
```