# Generic Type JSON model

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

this question may be trivially easy or quite hard. I do not really know Objective-C as a language but am trying to build an iPhone app anyway. I looked at [JSON Model](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) as a potential automagic data binding library for converting JSON objects into my domain models.

So here's my question. I have a purely RESTful API that returns resources with a common top level object similar to this:

```
{
    "successMessages": [],
    "errorMessages": [],
    "data": {}
}
```

In Java/Groovy, I use a similar library like Jackson to do this binding functionality and would write a class:

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T>{
    Collection successMessages
    Collection errorMessages
    T data
}
```

Such that a `ResponseWrapper<MyObject>` would be able to auto bind anything inside the JSON's `data` property to an object of type `MyObject`. I also use a common collection wrapper for all collections that's holds info on how to page and would like to use this same pattern if I could figure it out with some help! Does Objective-C support this kind of generic programming?

Comment: There's nothing native to the Objective-C language itself. Probably several libraries though (such as the one you mention in your first paragraph).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260961/how-to-create-model-classes-using-jsonmodel

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not sure how that question helps here. I get how to do the basic case of JSON model and relationships. It's this level of generics I don;t know. You are saying Objective-C doesn't offer this kind of programming model?

Comment: I'm saying Objective-C doesn't have built in support for JSON modeling (just like Java does not). In both cases you need some sort of library to do it easily.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support generic types. Is there a good reason you're trying to build a new app in Objective-C? Swift is mature enough for new projects to be successful using it and it is frankly a more productive language

Comment: project was started before swift was mature a few months back. don't feel like trying to wade thru two langs, especially when one is on the bleeding edge. I have access to a resource who knows Objective C (except hes unfamiliar with JSONModel).  also not all the libraries I want to use are supported in swift

Comment: @rikkigibson Would you please add swift code. In such a case you will see, why it is no good idea to use a static typed programming language for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: It is simply *wrong* that Objective-C has no generics. The reason for this urban legend is that most developers do not know, what generics are. Generics are type-indifferent code. Period. That's the definition. Static typing languages as Java, Swift, C++ and so on need a special syntax for this to make the compiler know the concrete type of code at compile-time. Therefore they support generics only from editing to compiling. In dynamic typing languages you do not need any extra $whatever, because generics are built-in for free from editing to runtime. This is more powerful and less language complexity.

To your Q:

In Objective-C you would simply create your classes as you would without taking JSON transfer into account. You do not have to take care about this. I. e. the result looks like this:

```
@interface ModelClass : NSObject
@property NSArray *successMessages;
@property NSArray *errorMessages;
@property AnotherClass data; // If you do not want to have concrete types here, use id
@end
```

To fill the properties you can use a framework. But this is not necessary. (And I would have some comments on JSON Model, however this is not the subject of the Q.)

To do it your own simply get the dictionary (JSON object) and create an instance from it:

```
@implementation NSObject (JSONToInstance)
- (id)initFromJSON:(NSDictionary*)JSON dataTypes:(NSDictionary*)types
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    for( NSString *key in JSON )
    {
      id value = JSON[key];
      NSDictionary *types = types[key];
      Class type = NSClassFromString(key);
      if (types)
      {
        id value = [[type alloc] initWithJSON:value dataType:types];
      }
      [self setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

To use it:

```
…
NSDictionary *JSON = …;
// Model refers to person and person has no "generic object" at all.
ModelClass *model = [[ModelClass alloc] initWithJSON:JSON dataTypes:@{ @"Person" : @()];
```

Typped in Safari.

But, of course, you can use a library. (I personally prefer to be as concrete as possible, even this means to have more concrete code. But I'm a developer, not a secretary.)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C does have newly added Generics. However they are not as fully realised as they are in Java. In Objective-C you can use them on interfaces, but in the implementations you have to use the `id` or base type of the generic definition.

I wrote a [blog post](http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/) where I show how it works. Hopefully that should answer your questions.

Comment: that's a rad blog post, @drekka, thanks for sharing that!

Comment: Have you ever had the wrong class in a collection in production code? I did polls about that in internet and on talks. The result: < 0,1 %. No one needs, what some calls generics, suffering from a misunderstanding.